# can a computer be totally made up of SRAM?

Tags: memory-hardware

can a computer be totally made up of SRAM with no DRAM but with secondary memory and run an opreating system properly?

Comment: Have a look at the time different implementations of computer memory came into use.

Comment: A computer cannot be totally made up of SRAM. It also needs a CPU.

Comment: yeah with a CPU

Comment: Sure can! It's just more expensive, so they don't. Guarantee your CPU cache is made of SRAM. A 64KB SRAM chip (the type you might find in a really old computer) now costs about €3 according to Google.

Comment: Some early computers used magnetic disks as the core memory.

Comment: <https://hackaday.com/2017/02/02/the-gray-1-a-computer-composed-entirely-of-rom-and-ram/>

Answer (score 1):

Certain early personal computers in fact used SRAM as their main source of memory. The ZX80 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Cray X-MP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray_X-MP) super computer. It uses SRAM instead of DRAM.